# Heroku deployment succes but no module found

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku, deployment

I am deploying the polls app from django tutorial to heroku.

My project seen from Pycharm have the following distribution:
[image]

My **requirements** file looks as:

```
Django==2.0.5
scikit-learn==0.19.1
numpy==1.13.3
pandas==0.22.0
pymysql==0.8.1
gunicorn==19.0.0
```

**Runtime** as:

```
python-3.6.5
```

**Procfile** as:

```
web: gunicorn inf-shf-373.wsgi:application --log-file -
```

When I deploy the app and goes to the browser I get an application error that says:

```
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

I retrieve the log using the `heroku logs --tail --app inf-shf-373`
 statement.

**Log**

```
2018-06-15T10:08:51.529196+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2018-06-15T10:08:51.529198+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 356, in import_app
2018-06-15T10:08:51.529201+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'inf-shf-373'
2018-06-15T10:08:51.529199+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2018-06-15T10:08:51.529202+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-06-15T10:08:51.529203+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 502, in spawn_worker
2018-06-15T10:08:51.529205+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2018-06-15T10:08:51.529206+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 114, in init_process
2018-06-15T10:08:51.529208+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2018-06-15T10:08:51.529209+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 66, in wsgi
2018-06-15T10:08:51.529211+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2018-06-15T10:08:51.529212+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2018-06-15T10:08:51.529216+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2018-06-15T10:08:51.529214+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2018-06-15T10:08:51.529218+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2018-06-15T10:08:51.529219+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 356, in import_app
2018-06-15T10:08:51.529221+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2018-06-15T10:08:51.529222+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'inf-shf-373'
2018-06-15T10:08:51.529340+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-06-15 10:08:51 [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2018-06-15T10:08:51.568925+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-06-15T10:08:51.568993+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
2018-06-15T10:08:51.569405+00:00 app[web.1]: load_entry_point('gunicorn==19.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'gunicorn')()
2018-06-15T10:08:51.569437+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 74, in run
2018-06-15T10:08:51.569696+00:00 app[web.1]: WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
2018-06-15T10:08:51.569725+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 166, in run
2018-06-15T10:08:51.570022+00:00 app[web.1]: super(Application, self).run()
2018-06-15T10:08:51.570050+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 71, in run
2018-06-15T10:08:51.570255+00:00 app[web.1]: Arbiter(self).run()
2018-06-15T10:08:51.570283+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 169, in run
2018-06-15T10:08:51.570559+00:00 app[web.1]: self.manage_workers()
2018-06-15T10:08:51.570587+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 477, in manage_workers
2018-06-15T10:08:51.571398+00:00 app[web.1]: self.spawn_workers()
2018-06-15T10:08:51.571426+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 537, in spawn_workers
2018-06-15T10:08:51.572443+00:00 app[web.1]: time.sleep(0.1 * random.random())
2018-06-15T10:08:51.572572+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in handle_chld
2018-06-15T10:08:51.573025+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2018-06-15T10:08:51.573611+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 459, in reap_workers
2018-06-15T10:08:51.574215+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2018-06-15T10:08:51.574320+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2018-06-15T10:08:51.656203+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-06-15T10:08:51.766089+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-06-15T10:08:51.768196+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-06-15T10:08:59.756644+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn inf-shf-373.wsgi:application --log-file -`
2018-06-15T10:09:01.853255+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-06-15T10:09:01.754462+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-06-15 10:09:01 [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.0.0
2018-06-15T10:09:01.754969+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-06-15 10:09:01 [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:24374 (4)
2018-06-15T10:09:01.755073+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-06-15 10:09:01 [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2018-06-15T10:09:01.758731+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-06-15 10:09:01 [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2018-06-15T10:09:01.762508+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-06-15 10:09:01 [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
2018-06-15T10:09:01.762510+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-06-15T10:09:01.762511+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 502, in spawn_worker
2018-06-15T10:09:01.762513+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2018-06-15T10:09:01.762514+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 114, in init_process
2018-06-15T10:09:01.762515+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2018-06-15T10:09:01.762516+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 66, in wsgi
2018-06-15T10:09:01.762517+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2018-06-15T10:09:01.762519+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2018-06-15T10:09:01.762520+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2018-06-15T10:09:01.762521+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2018-06-15T10:09:01.762522+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2018-06-15T10:09:01.762523+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 356, in import_app
2018-06-15T10:09:01.762524+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2018-06-15T10:09:01.762525+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'inf-shf-373'
2018-06-15T10:09:01.762526+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-06-15T10:09:01.762527+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 502, in spawn_worker
2018-06-15T10:09:01.762528+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2018-06-15T10:09:01.762529+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 114, in init_process
2018-06-15T10:09:01.762530+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2018-06-15T10:09:01.762532+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 66, in wsgi
2018-06-15T10:09:01.762533+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2018-06-15T10:09:01.762534+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2018-06-15T10:09:01.762535+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2018-06-15T10:09:01.762536+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2018-06-15T10:09:01.762537+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2018-06-15T10:09:01.762538+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 356, in import_app
2018-06-15T10:09:01.762543+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'inf-shf-373'
2018-06-15T10:09:01.762539+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2018-06-15T10:09:01.762635+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-06-15 10:09:01 [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2018-06-15T10:09:01.790830+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-06-15T10:09:01.790840+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
2018-06-15T10:09:01.791070+00:00 app[web.1]: load_entry_point('gunicorn==19.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'gunicorn')()
2018-06-15T10:09:01.791073+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 74, in run
2018-06-15T10:09:01.791209+00:00 app[web.1]: WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
2018-06-15T10:09:01.791216+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 166, in run
2018-06-15T10:09:01.791357+00:00 app[web.1]: super(Application, self).run()
2018-06-15T10:09:01.791360+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 71, in run
2018-06-15T10:09:01.791467+00:00 app[web.1]: Arbiter(self).run()
2018-06-15T10:09:01.791470+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 169, in run
2018-06-15T10:09:01.791600+00:00 app[web.1]: self.manage_workers()
2018-06-15T10:09:01.791603+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 477, in manage_workers
2018-06-15T10:09:01.791814+00:00 app[web.1]: self.spawn_workers()
2018-06-15T10:09:01.791816+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 537, in spawn_workers
2018-06-15T10:09:01.792051+00:00 app[web.1]: time.sleep(0.1 * random.random())
2018-06-15T10:09:01.792055+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in handle_chld
2018-06-15T10:09:01.792184+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2018-06-15T10:09:01.792187+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 459, in reap_workers
2018-06-15T10:09:01.792383+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2018-06-15T10:09:01.792417+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2018-06-15T10:09:01.897234+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-06-15T10:09:15.812856+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=inf-shf-373.herokuapp.com request_id=32838b77-14c1-4235-8ac1-9823f14dab4b fwd="80.94.4.53" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I believe that setting.py at my project directory doesn't have an app called `inf-shf-373`, but it is the random name created by heroku. This means that my whole app name, and then the references at `Procfile` should be `surveys` (I changed the polls name to surveys despite the tutorial).

Any reference to what is the problem?

**EDIT**
Answering DanielRoseman:
The wsgi.py file is at: code/computationalMarketing/computationalMarketing/wsgi.py

Extra information:
Is it possible that the problem can be that the wsgi.py file is not in the main path of the repo? The django project is the first computationalMarketing folder (this project is all gathered at code folder), the other folders that exists at the same level are sql mods, and vagrant files.

Comment: There is nothing in your code called inf-shf-373. Where exactly is your wsgi.py file?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I do not have this file, at least I have not created yet. I am able to work with the website using django runserver. Why I am not able using heroku?

Comment: @DanielRoseman the wsgi.py file is at: code/computationalMarketing/computationalMarketing/wsgi.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have been able to solve this question.

I have found the parameter `chdir` at `gunicorn`, which stablish the path to the `wsgi.py` file at django app.

An example:

```
web: gunicorn --chdir code/computationalMarketing computationalMarketing.wsgi --log-file -
```